# Analog and Digital Clock not working, I guess error is in HTML or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, time, clock

So, I followed a simple YouTube tutorial for making a Analog and Digital Clock. I did the exact same things as he did but my clock is not showing the time. YouTube Video Link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yXFiTDfhSXo. Please help I have worked really hard on this one. I guess it is a JavaScript or HTML error, but there is a very little chance that it is a CSS error. Do help if you know the solution

```js
let hr = document.querySelector('#hr');
            let mn = document.querySelector('#mn');
            let sc = document.querySelector('#sc');
    
            setInterval(() => {
                let date = new Date(); 
                let hh = day.GetHours() * 30;
                let mm = day.getMinutes() * 6;
                let ss = day.getSeconds() * 6;
    
                hr.style.transform = `rotateZ(${hh+(mm/12)}deg)`;
                mn.style.transform = `rotateZ(${mm}deg)`;
                sc.style.transform = `rotateZ(${ss}deg)`;
                // Digital Clock
                let hours = document.getElementById('hours');
                let minutes = document.getElementById('minutes');
                let seconds = document.getElementById('seconds');
                let ampm = document.getElementById('ampm');
    
                let h = new Date().getHours();
                let m = new Date().getMinutes();
                let s = new Date().getSeconds();
                let am = h >= 12 ? "PM" : "AM";
    
                if (h > 12) {
                    h = h - 12
                }
    
                h = (h < 10) ? "0" + h : h
                m = (m < 10) ? "0" + m : m
                s = (s < 10) ? "0" + s : s
    
                hours.innerHTML = h;
                minutes.innerHTML = m;
                seconds.innerHTML = s;
                ampm.innerHTML = am;
            })
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@100;200;300;400;500;600;700;800;900&display=swap');
    
    * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    }
    
    body {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        min-height: 100vh;
        background: #2f363e;
    }
    
    .container {
        position: relative;
        background: #2f363e;
        /* min-height: 500px; */
        border-radius: 20px;
        border-top-left-radius: 225px;
        border-top-right-radius: 225px;
        box-shadow: 25px 25px 75px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75),
            10px 50px 70px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25),
            inset 5px 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), inset 5px 5px 20px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), inset -5px -5px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        flex-direction: column;
    }
    
    .clock {
        position: relative;
        width: 450px;
        height: 450px;
        background: #2f363e;
        border-radius: 50%;
        box-shadow: 10px 50px 70px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25),
            inset 5px 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), inset 5px 5px 20px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), inset -5px -5px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        margin-bottom: 30px;
    }
    
    .clock::before {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        width: 8px;
        height: 8px;
        background: #2f363e;
        border: 3px solid #fff;
        border-radius: 50%;
        z-index: 100000;
    }
    
    .clock span {
        position: absolute;
        inset: 20px;
        color: #fff;
        text-align: center;
        transform: rotate(calc(30deg * var(--i)));
    }
    
    .clock span b {
        font-size: 2em;
        opacity: 0.25;
        font-weight: 600;
        display: inline-block;
        transform: rotate(calc(-30deg * var(--i)));
    }
    
    .circle {
        position: absolute;
        width: 300px;
        height: 300px;
        border: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
        border-radius: 50%;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: flex-start;
        z-index: 10;
    }
    
    .circle i {
        position: absolute;
        width: 6px;
        height: 50%;
        background: var(--clr);
        opacity: 0.75;
        transform-origin: bottom;
        transform: scaleY(0.5);
    }
    
    .circle:nth-child(1) i {
        width: 2px;
    }
    
    .circle:nth-child(2) i {
        width: 6px;
    }
    
    .circle2 {
        width: 240px;
        height: 240px;
        z-index: 9;
    }
    
    .circle3 {
        width: 180px;
        height: 180px;
        z-index: 8;
    }
    
    .circle::before {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        top: -8.5px;
        width: 15px;
        height: 15px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        background: var(--clr);
        box-shadow: 0 0 20px var(--clr),
            0 0 60px var(--clr);
    }
    
    #time {
        margin-bottom: 40px;
        display: flex;
        padding: 10px 20px;
        font-size: 2em;
        font-weight: 600;
        border: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
        border-radius: 40px;
        box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5),
            inset 5px 5px 20px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2),
            inset -5px -5px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
    }
    
    #time div {
        position: relative;
        width: 60px;
        text-align: center;
        font-weight: 500;
        color: var(--clr);
    }
    
    #time div:nth-child(1)::after,
    #time div:nth-child(2)::after {
        content: ':';
        position: absolute;
        right: -4px;
    }
    
    #time div:last-child {
        font-size: 0.7em;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        color: #fff;
    }
```

```html
<body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="clock">
    
                <div class="circle" id="sc" style="--clr:#04fc43"><i></i></div>
                <div class="circle circle2" id="mn" style="--clr:#fee800"><i></i></div>
                <div class="circle circle3" id="hr" style="--clr:#ff2972"><i></i></div>
    
                <span style="--i:1;"><b>1</b></span>
                <span style="--i:2;"><b>2</b></span>
                <span style="--i:3;"><b>3</b></span>
                <span style="--i:4;"><b>4</b></span>
                <span style="--i:5;"><b>5</b></span>
                <span style="--i:6;"><b>6</b></span>
                <span style="--i:7;"><b>7</b></span>
                <span style="--i:8;"><b>8</b></span>
                <span style="--i:9;"><b>9</b></span>
                <span style="--i:10;"><b>10</b></span>
                <span style="--i:11;"><b>11</b></span>
                <span style="--i:12;"><b>12</b></span>
            </div>
    
            <!-- Digital Clock -->
            <div id="time">
                <div id="hours" style="--clr:#ff2972">00</div>
                <div id="minutes" style="--clr:#fee800">00</div>
                <div id="seconds" style="--clr:#04fc43">00</div>
                <div id="ampm">AM</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
```

Comment: If you run your code snippet you should see errors stacking up (on each 'tick') or if you run your own code somewhere else, use your browsers' dev tools inspect facility, you should see the errors listed. I saw day not being defined for example.

Answer (score 2):

there are a very few silly mistakes
when you started the `setInterval`

```
 let date = new Date(); 
 let hh = day.GetHours() * 30;
 let mm = day.getMinutes() * 6;
 let ss = day.getSeconds() * 6;
```

here you defined date but you are using `day(day.Gethours())`
and the **g** should not be capital at the `date.gethours()`
and that's all replace the above code by the code given below , it will work

```
let date = new Date(); 
let hh = date.getHours() * 30;
let mm = date.getMinutes() * 6;
let ss = date.getSeconds() * 6;
```

Answer (score 0):

you define `let date` as `new Date()` and then use `day` instead of `date`

```
 setInterval(() => {
  let date = new Date(); 
  let hh = day.getHours() * 30;  == should be =>  let hh = date.getHours() * 30;
  let mm = day.getMinutes() * 6; == should be =>  let mm = date.getMinutes() * 6;
  let ss = day.getSeconds() * 6; == should be =>  let ss = date.getSeconds() * 6;
```

```js
let hr = document.querySelector('#hr');
            let mn = document.querySelector('#mn');
            let sc = document.querySelector('#sc');
    
            setInterval(() => {
                let date = new Date(); 
                let hh = date.getHours() * 30;
                let mm = date.getMinutes() * 6;
                let ss = date.getSeconds() * 6;
    
                hr.style.transform = `rotateZ(${hh+(mm/12)}deg)`;
                mn.style.transform = `rotateZ(${mm}deg)`;
                sc.style.transform = `rotateZ(${ss}deg)`;
                // Digital Clock
                let hours = document.getElementById('hours');
                let minutes = document.getElementById('minutes');
                let seconds = document.getElementById('seconds');
                let ampm = document.getElementById('ampm');
    
                let h = new Date().getHours();
                let m = new Date().getMinutes();
                let s = new Date().getSeconds();
                let am = h >= 12 ? "PM" : "AM";
    
                if (h > 12) {
                    h = h - 12
                }
    
                h = (h < 10) ? "0" + h : h
                m = (m < 10) ? "0" + m : m
                s = (s < 10) ? "0" + s : s
    
                hours.innerHTML = h;
                minutes.innerHTML = m;
                seconds.innerHTML = s;
                ampm.innerHTML = am;
            })
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@100;200;300;400;500;600;700;800;900&display=swap');
    
    * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    }
    
    body {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        min-height: 100vh;
        background: #2f363e;
    }
    
    .container {
        position: relative;
        background: #2f363e;
        /* min-height: 500px; */
        border-radius: 20px;
        border-top-left-radius: 225px;
        border-top-right-radius: 225px;
        box-shadow: 25px 25px 75px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75),
            10px 50px 70px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25),
            inset 5px 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), inset 5px 5px 20px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), inset -5px -5px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        flex-direction: column;
    }
    
    .clock {
        position: relative;
        width: 450px;
        height: 450px;
        background: #2f363e;
        border-radius: 50%;
        box-shadow: 10px 50px 70px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25),
            inset 5px 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), inset 5px 5px 20px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), inset -5px -5px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        margin-bottom: 30px;
    }
    
    .clock::before {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        width: 8px;
        height: 8px;
        background: #2f363e;
        border: 3px solid #fff;
        border-radius: 50%;
        z-index: 100000;
    }
    
    .clock span {
        position: absolute;
        inset: 20px;
        color: #fff;
        text-align: center;
        transform: rotate(calc(30deg * var(--i)));
    }
    
    .clock span b {
        font-size: 2em;
        opacity: 0.25;
        font-weight: 600;
        display: inline-block;
        transform: rotate(calc(-30deg * var(--i)));
    }
    
    .circle {
        position: absolute;
        width: 300px;
        height: 300px;
        border: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
        border-radius: 50%;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: flex-start;
        z-index: 10;
    }
    
    .circle i {
        position: absolute;
        width: 6px;
        height: 50%;
        background: var(--clr);
        opacity: 0.75;
        transform-origin: bottom;
        transform: scaleY(0.5);
    }
    
    .circle:nth-child(1) i {
        width: 2px;
    }
    
    .circle:nth-child(2) i {
        width: 6px;
    }
    
    .circle2 {
        width: 240px;
        height: 240px;
        z-index: 9;
    }
    
    .circle3 {
        width: 180px;
        height: 180px;
        z-index: 8;
    }
    
    .circle::before {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        top: -8.5px;
        width: 15px;
        height: 15px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        background: var(--clr);
        box-shadow: 0 0 20px var(--clr),
            0 0 60px var(--clr);
    }
    
    #time {
        margin-bottom: 40px;
        display: flex;
        padding: 10px 20px;
        font-size: 2em;
        font-weight: 600;
        border: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
        border-radius: 40px;
        box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5),
            inset 5px 5px 20px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2),
            inset -5px -5px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
    }
    
    #time div {
        position: relative;
        width: 60px;
        text-align: center;
        font-weight: 500;
        color: var(--clr);
    }
    
    #time div:nth-child(1)::after,
    #time div:nth-child(2)::after {
        content: ':';
        position: absolute;
        right: -4px;
    }
    
    #time div:last-child {
        font-size: 0.7em;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        color: #fff;
    }
```

```html
<body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="clock">
    
                <div class="circle" id="sc" style="--clr:#04fc43"><i></i></div>
                <div class="circle circle2" id="mn" style="--clr:#fee800"><i></i></div>
                <div class="circle circle3" id="hr" style="--clr:#ff2972"><i></i></div>
    
                <span style="--i:1;"><b>1</b></span>
                <span style="--i:2;"><b>2</b></span>
                <span style="--i:3;"><b>3</b></span>
                <span style="--i:4;"><b>4</b></span>
                <span style="--i:5;"><b>5</b></span>
                <span style="--i:6;"><b>6</b></span>
                <span style="--i:7;"><b>7</b></span>
                <span style="--i:8;"><b>8</b></span>
                <span style="--i:9;"><b>9</b></span>
                <span style="--i:10;"><b>10</b></span>
                <span style="--i:11;"><b>11</b></span>
                <span style="--i:12;"><b>12</b></span>
            </div>
    
            <!-- Digital Clock -->
            <div id="time">
                <div id="hours" style="--clr:#ff2972">00</div>
                <div id="minutes" style="--clr:#fee800">00</div>
                <div id="seconds" style="--clr:#04fc43">00</div>
                <div id="ampm">AM</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
```